# How to compute log returns on assets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compute the log returns of a stock using the formula:

```
X=log(pt)-log(pt-1)
```

The code I made, doesn't work:

> runtime error Q invalid procedure call or argument

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim row As Integer
row = 9

Do While Cells(row, 2) <> ""
    Cells(row, 4).Value = log(Cells(row + 1, 2).Value) - log(Cells(row, 2).Value)
    row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error of some sort (what error?), or is the output just not what you expected?

Comment: there is a runtime errorQ invallid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran outside the bounds of your data. When `Cells(row, 2)` gets to the last row your data, you try to evaluate something equivalent to `Log(Number) - Log(0)` because `Cells(row + 1, 2)` is empty and defaults to 0. And of course, `Log(0)` is invalid and throws an error.

Fix this by adjusting your loop (start at second row and calculate with the cell above it).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim row As Integer
row = 10


Do While Cells(row, 2) <> ""
    Cells(row - 1, 4).Value = Log(Cells(row, 2).Value) - Log(Cells(row - 1, 2).Value)
    row = row + 1
Loop


End Sub
```